# String Comparison not working C

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

I came across a weird problem in c programming today. I wrote a program for server client communication and applied the string comparison function on it but the function doesn't work if I compare a string with stuff inside buf. I also checked if data in buf is different than what I am entering after a few iteration but results were negative and the data is the same as I am entering. Then why does `strcmp` is not working. Here is the code:

```
char buf[1024];
while(1)
{
    int readbytes=read(communFd,buf,1024);

    write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,readbytes);


   if(!strcmp(buf,"exitChat"))
    {
        printf("Chat terminating...\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: If the data was the same, like you claim it is, then `strcmp` would return `0` as it should.

Comment: `read` doesn't 0-terminate.

Comment: "I also checked" \[how?\]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`read()` does not null terminate the buffer which `strcmp()` depends upon, you must do this explicitly:

```
int readbytes=read(communFd,buf,1023); /* Read one less for null terminator. */
if (readBytes != -1)
{
    buf[readBytes] = 0;
    if(!strcmp(buf,"exitChat"))
    {
    }
}
```

Or, as mentioned by others use a different function that does not depend upon the presence of the null terminator character.

Note that [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) does not guarantee that the requested number of bytes is read and it is not considered an error if less bytes is read. From the linked reference page:

> **On success, the number of bytes read is returned** (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number. **It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested;** this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately. In this case it is left unspecified whether the file position (if any) changes.

To ensure that a full message has been received you will need to add data to text being sent so the receiver knows when it has received a complete message. This could be:

- preceding the text with its length.
- using a sentinel value to indicate the end of a message, for example a `\n` character to indicate the end. The structure of the code would change to call `read()` in a loop until the `\n` is found while appending each byte read to an array.

Comment: ok so I tried with concatenating the input string with single space, the resultant string will be null terminated but still it is not working

Comment: @JamesAflred, there is no concatentation here. The line `buf[readBytes] = 0;` assigns null terminator to that index. Print out `buf` after assigning the null terminator to check if the content is as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` will compare two null-terminated char arrays.  `read` will not null-terminate buffers you read from a file descriptor.  Unless you know there should be `'\0'` bytes in your file, you could try using `strncmp(buf,"exitChat", sizeof("exitChat")-1)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `readbytes`, compare only that many bytes:

```
if(!strncmp(buf,"exitChat",readbytes))
```